# Position Modal box in Twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I'm trying to have a Twitter bootstrap 3 modal appear fixed to the top right corner of the body.

So far I've tried:

- position: fixed; right 0px (left and top works but right has no affect)
- translate: can get it working with px values or % but position will not be same when resizing
- Setting the left margin as percentage

CSS in question:

```
#confirm { 
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 120px !important;
  right: 10px !important;      
//margin-left: 80% !important;
//-webkit-transform: translate(600px, 0px);
}
```

See the fiddle bellow:
http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/74/

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: He's trying to have a bootstrap modal dialog appear on the top-right instead of the top-left

Comment: Try mentioning `left: <some_val>px !important;` instead of `right` in css.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap applies `left: 1%;` and `right: 1%;` to the modal box by default.

First, you need to reset the `left` property to `auto`. Then you could add the `right` property for the element.

```css
#confirm {
  width: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  left: auto; /* <-- Reset the default left value */
  right: 10px;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3kgbG/76/)**.